# questions about characteristic classes

Tags: algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes

I have few questions about studying characteristic classes.

1. Without (at least in the immediate future) going into the obstruction theory, do I need to concider cohomology with coefficients in arbitrary ring $\Lambda$ and treat cohomology groups as the $\Lambda$-modules. Motivation of this question is that I noticed that usually there are cohomology with coeficcients in $\mathbb{Z}_2$.
2. It is possible (resonable) to start studying characteristic classes and K-theory parallel? I mean, both areas are new for me, but I would like to know 'applications' of characteristic classes in K-theory. Or maybe is it too hard (not resonable) at the beggining?

Comment: (1) Do you need to consider cohomology with coefficients for what? Characteristic classes in general? (2) Sure.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but for $1$, sure why not, but this is not the biggest deal. For example, you can dualize homology with $\mathbb Z/2Z$ coefficients. (2) It makes sense to me, Hatcher's book covers $k$-theory first, but I dont think that they are logically dependent (although there is interplay.)

Comment: you mean that treating characteristic classes as such a tool in K-theory doesn't make sense (you wrote that it makes sense to you but I don't understand the second part of the sentence)

Answer (score 1):

1) No, not in that generality. If you want to study real vector bundles you will encounter cohomology with $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients. If you study complex vector bundles you will get $\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients.

2) It is possible and reasonable to study these things parallel. I have done so (using Atiyah's and Milnor-Stasheff at the same time). I do not like MS treatment of the construction of the classes (chapter 10 maybe?) so I would look for another source for that (for example Hatcher's notes).